# Slow internet connection on Android phone, while no issues on other home devices

Tags: wi-fi, router, internet

I'm having an issue with the WiFi connection on my Android phone (OnePlus 6, Android 11). For the past few days, **some apps started to work slowly**, I see spinners all the time, indicating that the contents of the apps cannot be loaded.

**As soon as I switch to mobile data** (LTE) everything is OK. Also, other home devices (2 laptops and an iPhone have no internet issues).

**What I tried:**

- Changing the position of my router. No luck.
- I used a WiFi Analyzer app to find more optimal channels to use and I manually set them on the router. At first, setting a channel helps (the slow apps start working well again), but after a while, the problem comes back and the apps become slow again.

The router provides both 2 and 5GHz frequencies, applied automatically whenever possible. My internet speed is ~500Mbps.

Is it my phone or is it my network? No clue. How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: When you connect on your phone are you using 2.4g or 5g?  What standard are you using for your WIFI connection (ie 802.11n + AC or something else?)   It sounds to me like you are trying to connect your phone in the 2.4 gig band which is congested - with other AP's changing their frequency to get more bandwidth.

Comment: @davidgo When connected, I'm using 5g. The standard used is 802.11 a/n/ac (another available in the settings is 802.11 n/ac)

Comment: drop 802.11a.  It peobably wont fix the problem but its obsolete.

Comment: Just want to confirm that the issue is with the *slow* internet connection, not *no* internet connection, right?

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly. Oddly enough, my internet speed is high, but the problem on my phone remains.